# Trouble including a file in multipart/form-data POST using RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp

I'm relatively new to web interactions with C# and I'm having some trouble making a POST request to upload a file using an API. The API only accepts the files as part of a multipart/form-data section in the body. At other's suggestions I've been trying to use RestSharp to do this, but I can't seem to get the file itself into the POST. Chunks of code derived from Postman suggested code - where the POST works.

I've tried a few things. This chunk resulted in a POST going through with the correct parameter in the body, but no file was included.

```
var client = new RestClient(postURL);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", string.Format("------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upfile\"; filename=\"{0}\"\r\nContent-Type: application/xml\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"overwrite\"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", xmlPath), ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string test = response.Content.ToString();
```

I also tried some variations of AddFile - physical file path, byte array, and byte array with content type = application/xml. With these iterations, I was able to get a file to post, but the overwrite parameter wasn't coming through correctly to force a file overwrite.

```
var client = new RestClient(postURL);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
// The different part below
request.AddFile("upfile", @xmlPath);
request.AddParameter("multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW", "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"overwrite\"\r\n\r\ntrue\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string test = response.Content.ToString();
```

*note: I'm using an older version of RestSharp (105.2.3) to be compatible with .Net 4.0 (stuck with it in this case).

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out after sleeping on it, was really simple in the end. All of the extra webkit and multipart stuff that was throwing me for a loop is entirely unnecessary - autogenerated code from Postman is overly complicated it seems.

```
var client = new RestClient(postURL);
var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
request.AddHeader("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW");
request.AddFile("upfile", @xmlPath);
request.AddParameter("overwrite", "true", ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string test = response.Content.ToString();
```